# Mule:Testing HTTP Service on MMC

Tags: mule

I have deployed my application running on my local server @ http://localhost:8048/myservice?day=xx&month=yy&year=zzzz , it works succesfully on my local machine, in that it downloads a file from the http site. However when I deploy to Mule Management console . I understand that the default port is 8585. When I change the URL to MMC & give the default port with the same path, it does not download the file . Am I missingsomething

Answer (score 0):

The MMC is a utility for managing and monitoring  Mule Standalone Runtimes.
One of its functions is to deploy apps to a Runtime. You are not actually deploying to the MMC.

Does this help clarify the situation or do you want any further help on want The MMC is used for and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the logs inside MMC.It stores the logfiles date wise.See if your application has been deployed in MMC successfully and if yes then do the following things:

1)If you are using any path to download the file then cross check the path details.You can put a logger to crosscheck that.
2)Put a logger before the business logic and after the business logic and follow what it is logging in the log file.

3)In case your server is Linux then check the path separator pattern

Answer (score -1):

MMC is a Mule Management Console which is used (provides provision) to deploy, undeploy, manage, monitor application and server both. From the statement you mentioned in your query it seems you are trying to deploy the app in the MMC - MMC is not a server its a console where you can register your ESB Runtimes -or- API Gateways (on-Prem) servers so that you can deploy the applications to the server/runtimes (which will go to the runtimes location $MULE_HOME/apps).

Please check if you have registered the server under MMC's Server tab - if not then you have to do this first and then it will allow you to perform application deployment using the MMC's APplication tab where you can upload your deployment archive/artifacts/build to the mmc repo and then you can deploy through the deployment options by selecting your server (which you have registered).

If I am missing something from your statement then please clarify more and will try to help you out here.